# How do I set qt creator quick fix to fix only a single project?

Tags: qt-creator

I have two separate projects, one is already written, and the other is being written.There are a pair of the same header and source files in these two projects, and the same sets of functions.

When I tried to use Alt+Enter to generate a function definition in the project I was writing, there would be no reaction. If I press Shift+F2, I will jump to the function definition in the old project. How can I set it to let the Quick Fix contain only files in the current active project?